# bot.users.get is no longer a function?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, chatbot

Making a currency System for my Discord Bot. I'm used to Discord.js V11, so I don't know if I am just being stupid. I'm getting TypeError: bot.users.get is not a function. If someone could help me out, that would be great.

```
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const colours = require("../colours.json");
const money = require("../money.json");
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if(!args[0]) {
        var user = message.author;
    } else {
        var user = message.mentions.users.first() || bot.users.get(args[0]);
    }

    if(!money[user.id]) {
        money [user.id] = {
            name: bot.users.get(user.id).tag,
            money: 0
        }
        fs.writeFile("./money.json", JSON.stringify(money), (err) => {
            if(err) console.log(err);
        });
    }

    return message.channel.send(`${bot.users.get(user.id).username} has $${money[user.id].money}.`);
}
```

Comment: What is `bot.users.get`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 2):

Discord.js v12 implemented a [UserManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager), that has a cache

What you want is `Client.users.cache.get(user.id)`